# How to setup TFS 2018 kanban board to show only leaf work items (User Stories)

Tags: tfs, kanban

Is there a way how to display only **leaf** work items (User Stories and not Features, Epics or higher) in TFS 2018.3.1 Kanban board?
It was working fine in TFS 2017.3 and after upgrade it started to show all work items.
Our User Stories, Features and Epics are all defined as Backlog Items as subtypes.

Thanks for help.